# The gifts of other folk

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

We know that Men (including hobbits) are gifted Doom, and the Elves are gifted immortality, but what are the other gifts? What did Eru Ilúvatar give to the others?

Comment: Who? The dwarves weren’t in Eru’s original plan.

Comment: I know, but they have something after death, because otherwise they have doom as well. Beings like Beorn, the orcs too. @amaranth

Comment: @amaranth but He found a way to fit them in. I've searched SF&F but can't find a question where someone asked what happens to Dwarves (or Ents for that matter) when they die.

Comment: I don't know that immortality is ever described as a gift. Do you have an instance in mind? And why do you differentiate between "gift" and "doom"?

Comment: I don't have a particular instance in mind. And I differentiate "doom" and "gift" only to name this gift. @MattGutting

Comment: @BalinSonOfFundin So, are you asking essentially "What happens to races other than humans and elves after death?" because I'm pretty sure we have a answers to that question on the site.

Comment: Didn't find one, sorry. But the final step yes, what happens to ents, orcs, skin-changers, eagles, etc. @MattGutting

Comment: Would giving longer lifespan to Númenórean count as a gift?

Comment: No, the gifts are not longer lifespan, or pointy ears, only gifts that Eru gave to the beings of Arda. @isanae

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin: Orcs are either Elves or Men. Skin-changers are men.

Comment: @shamshiel and yet the orcs are corrupted elves or men, but I can't see the skin-changers as humans, is there a source to this statement?

Comment: Do you agree with the dupe? We might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin: *"Others say that he is a man descended from the first men who lived before Smaug and the other dragons came into this part of the world, and before the goblins came into the hills out of the North. I cannot say, though I fancy [this] is the true tale."*